# How to find the mapping between ubertooth device number and USB path and port?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, usb

I have a system with two (or more for that matter) ubertooth sticks connected. I command them with

ubertooth-util -U devNumber ...

and

ubertooth-rxtx -U devNumber ...

with devNumber from {0, 1} respectively. I have them connected to a USB hub with per port power switching (supported by uhubctl) so that whenever one gets in a bad state I can switch them off, unbind them and switch them on again.

But which "devNumber" is connected to which port of the USB hub? For devices like USB WLAN cards this is simply done by observing their representation in the /sys-filesystem but the ubertooth sticks do not appear there since no dedicated driver touches them (at least that is what I understand).

I could switch the ports off one by one and check which device still takes a command to create the mapping.

Or I could issue "ubertooth-util -U devNumber -s" and "lsusb -v" and then map by serial number which seems even worse.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: They should still show up in lsusb output.

Comment: uhubctl is using semi-stable addressing for ports: b-x.y.z, where b is USB bus number, and x,y,z are port numbers for all hubs in chain, starting from root hub on USB bus. It means as long as you keep the same device connected to the same physical USB port, it's address will not change. However, device number per lsusb or device number in /dev/btN (or whatever it is called) will keep changing